# MYSQL Subract the value of the column in each row

Tags: mysql

i want to subtract each rows in a column using MySQL query. I fount the solution here on MSSQL https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/180b705c-08d9-467a-b247-814a8bb85a4a/how-can-can-i-subtract-the-value-of-the-column-in-each-row-?forum=transactsql, i tried it on MSSQL and it's working well. However, i tried using it on MySQL and change a lil bit query, and it's not working. This is my query

```
set @UpdatedQTY = 850;
UPDATE testsa
SET m1010=CASE WHEN @UpdatedQTY < 0 THEN 0 ELSE @UpdatedQTY END,
    @UpdatedQTY =  m1010-ABS(@UpdatedQTY)
WHERE m1010-ABS(@UpdatedQTY) < 0
```

and this is the response

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE testsa
>   SET 
>   m1010=CASE WHEN @UpdatedQTY < 0 THEN 0 ELSE @UpdatedQTY END' at line 2`

Can anyone works it on MySQL or MySQL didn't support that queries?

Comment: you forgot `;` after your first statement

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted contains two queries: `set @UpdatedQTY = 850` and `UPDATE testsa ...`.

Either you separate them and run them one by one or, if the tool or library you use allows running multiple queries, you have to use `;` to separate them.

To make the `UPDATE` statement easier to read you can use the [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function instead of the [`CASE` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
UPDATE testsa
SET m1010 = GREATEST(0, @UpdatedQTY),
   @UpdatedQTY = m1010 - ABS(@UpdatedQTY)
WHERE m1010 - ABS(@UpdatedQTY) < 0
```

To make it even more readable (and possibly faster) you can pre-compute `ABS(@UpdatedQTY)` and store it into another variable:

```
# This is probably set dynamically
SET @UpdatedQTY = 850;

# Compute its absolute value
SET @AbsQTY = ABS(@UpdatedQTY);

# Update the table
UPDATE testsa
SET m1010 = GREATEST(0, @UpdatedQTY),
   @UpdatedQTY = m1010 - @AbsQTY
WHERE m1010 < @AbsQTY
```

Comment: I'm still getting error, is this a problem on MySQL?
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @AbsQTY = ABS(@UpdatedQTY)

Comment: It seems the tool or library you are using cannot run two or more queries at once. How do you execute the queries?